# C# Deserializes everything into anyField

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-serialization

I am working on a C# project where I need to read and write xml files. Therefor I use a 3rd party open source xml schema. As some of the xsd elements in this schema are open for non-schema specific extensions they provide so called "anyField" child elements like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="eTrackElements">
  <xs:sequence>
    ...
    <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="strict" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    </xs:any>
    ...
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I have generated my C# code successfully using xsd.exe this way:

```
xsd.exe %XSD_IN% /c /language:CS /order /n:RailMLlib22 /o:%CS_OUT%
```

With that code I create an object structure and I am able to write/serialize it to a valid XML file. But when I try to read/deserialize this or any other (valid) xml file into an object tree, all elements inside "eTrackElements" don't land where they are suppossed to be, they all are deserialzed into the "anyField" although they are not special/extended and they are in the same namespace and they are standard elements of that xml schema.
The only way I can prevent this behaviour is commenting out the anyFields in my generated C# code:

```
// private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;
```

Then everything works fine! But this is a bad workaround how can I solve this problem better?

As the code is 25k lines of code this may be relevant part:

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
  [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.railml.org/schemas/2013")]
  public partial class eTrackElements {
  ...
    private tSpeedChange[] speedChangesField;
    ...
    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;
    ...

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("speedChange", IsNullable = false)]
    public tSpeedChange[] speedChanges
    {
      get
      {
        return this.speedChangesField;
      }
      set
      {
        this.speedChangesField = value;
      }
    }

    ...

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order = 17)]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
    {
      get
      {
        return this.anyField;
      }
      set
      {
        this.anyField = value;
     }
    }
```

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<railml xmlns:purl="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.railml.org/schemas/2013">
    <infrastructure>
        <tracks>
            <track type="mainTrack1" id="t1">
                <trackTopology>
                    <trackBegin id="t1start" pos="0">
                        <connection id="c1" ref="c2"/>
                    </trackBegin>
                    <trackEnd id="t1end" pos="1306">
                        <connection id="c3" ref="c4"/>
                    </trackEnd>
                    <connections>
                        <switch pos="1306" id="sw196">
                            <connection course="right" orientation="outgoing" id="5" ref="6"/>
                        </switch>
                    </connections>
                    <crossSections>
                        <crossSection ocpRef="OCP1" pos="332" id="cs1">
                            <geoCoord coord="..."/>
                        </crossSection>
                        <crossSection ocpRef="OCP2" pos="810" id="cs2">
                            <geoCoord coord="..."/>
                        </crossSection>
                        <crossSection ocpRef="OCP3" pos="1279" id="cs3">
                            <geoCoord coord="..."/>
                        </crossSection>
                    </crossSections>
                </trackTopology>
                <trackElements>
                    <gradientChanges>
                        <gradientChange slope="0" pos="0" id="gr1"/>
                        <gradientChange slope="2" pos="329" id="gr2"/>
                        <gradientChange slope="3" pos="808" id="gr3"/>
                        <gradientChange slope="4" pos="1299" id="gr4"/>
                        <gradientChange slope="4" pos="1306" id="gr5"/>
                    </gradientChanges>
                </trackElements>
            </track>
        </tracks>
    </infrastructure>
</railml>
```

I import the xml file this way:

```
  RailMLlib22.railml railML22 = null;
  FileStream file = null;
  try
  {
    file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
    railML22 = (RailMLlib22.railml)new XmlSerializer(typeof(RailMLlib22.railml)).Deserialize(file);
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    ...
  }
  finally
  {
    file.Close();
  }
```

Comment: post also generated object stucture

Comment: I added a relevant class, since the code is 25k lines I can't add all.

Comment: You need to show sample XML and code that reproduce the problem, but this is *probably* because you have set the `Order` property on your elements, and an unknown element is coming out of order.  Try manually removing the `Order = X` constraint and see what happens.

Comment: @dbc I added an xml example and the code to import it. If I remove 'Order' I get a System.InvalidOperationException during importing the xml, saying "Error during Reflecting type ...." on every type where I removed the 'Order' property, telling me I should add 'Order' inside XmlElement, XmlAnyElement or XmlArray

Comment: @DelPedro - just to confirm, you removed *all* the `Order = X` settings from the `XmlArrayAttribute`, `XmlElementAttribute` and `XmlAnyElementAttribute` attributes inside the `eTrackElements` class?  They must be present for all attributes, or present for none of them.

Comment: @dbc No sorry I didn't - one class was left with Order = X in its Annotation. Now I removed all, regenerated the code without /order, I have no exception anymore but the objects still go to "anyField".

Comment: Hi @DelPedro, we're trying to achieve the same thing you've tried here, only 6 years later. We ended up running into the same problem you have, namely that everything gets deserialized into anyFields. This happens on railML 2.2 files, weirdly enough not on railML 2.3 files. May we ask you: if you fixed this problem, how did you end up fixing it? As you're the only one who has asked this question on the web, we're really hoping you might be able to help us out.

Comment: Hi @Jesse, I just opened the old dusty code from 2016 and I am sorry to say, but it seems like we found no other solution than to comment out every anyField.

Comment: Hi @DelPedro, thanks for your comment! Though not the magical solution we were looking for, we’re really thankful for you trying to help us.